# Permissions issue when building a project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get a project to build on a machine but i get the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(744,5): warning MSB3075: The command "regsvr32 /s "C:\builds\working\\Win32\Debug\projx86.dll"" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
The previous error was converted to a warning because the task was called with ContinueOnError=true.
Build continuing because "ContinueOnError" on the task "Exec" is set to "true".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(756,5): error MSB8011: Failed to register output. Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.
```

The user account i am using is an Administrator on the machine so should that not have the highest privileges?

I can go to the startup and right click and run as administrator and that might sort it, but im trying to do an automated build and run of this project, so i cant use that method.

Anyone know how i might fix this?

Comment: `Linker > General > Register Output`, set the value to `"No"`

Comment: I think this is part of a bigger problem. I cant add enviornment variables either. There seems to be something wrong with the permissions on the user account. Its set as an administrator though so it should have complete access right?

Answer (score 13):

Solution Explorer ->[YourProject]->Properties->Linker ->General->Per-user Redirection "TRUE"

Answer (score 5):

I found this same issue when working on an C++ ATL project.

In my case, when I added a new ATL class I was missing a line in the resource file (.rc) that adds a resource type "registry" of the new class resource file (.rgs) . This creates the same permission issue stated above.

Comment: Would you mind showing how you solved that problem? In particular, what line did you add to the .rc file?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul you should add a line `IDR_<newATLClassObject>   REGISTRY                "<newATLClassObject>.rgs"` to your project .rc file; consequently, you should add a definition `IDR_<newATLClassObject> XXX` in your Resource.h file. Also make sure that your <newATLClassObject>.rgs file contains an adequate registry data as well.

Answer (score 5):

@LittleFairy answer is probably the best.  But you could run Visual Studio as administrator.

Note:  You need to explicitly start Visual Studio as administrator.  Just the user account having admin rights isn't enough.

Comment: I started as Administrator and still no joy

Comment: You save my day! Thanks.